# Hide file types in finder search

Tags: finder, file

Does anyone know how to hide certain file types from finder and spotlight search? I get all these files that I need on my computer but I will never use. I would like to hide them to make my searches more efficient. [image: screengrab]

Comment: Would an answer showing how to delimit your search *to* a specific file type be acceptable?

Comment: No not really, I need to work fast with as little steps as possible